# Best Mysql DB Engine When Insert update delete query is not made

Tags: mysql, database, myisam

What should be the best Mysql db engine When query like Update, Insert, Delete are barely made (99% of time are not made)

The database has a lots entry mainly numeric data type, 
the select query are based on conditional statement which compares numeric value and return results

Should i use MyISAM here ?

One more thing is The database will be used by multiple user at the same time

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with MyISAM over InnoDB for three(3) major reasons

**Reason # 1 : MyISAM storage engine provides simpler mechanisms for improving read performance**

MyISAM tables are comprised of just three files

- .frm (Format File)
- .MYD (Data File)
- .MYI (Index File)

You can tune MyISAM tables for faster reads with one simple change to the table's row format.

For example, Pages 71-73 of the book [MySQL Database Design and Tuning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672327651) recommends doing this to a MyISAM table:

```
ALTER TABLE tblname ROW_FORMAT=Fixed;
```

This will convert all VARCHARs to CHARs internally. Ths will also make the MyISAM table about 50% larger but have increased read performance because the string length is more rigidly checked with VARCHAR whereas a CHAR's length is fixed.

As an alternative you could run myisampack on a MyISAM table to reduce the MyISAM table size and create a new read-only format.

These are one-time operations you can perform on any MyISAM table. Changing the row format on an InnoDB table is somewhat useless due to its clustered index layout (explained in Reason # 3)

**Reason # 2 : MyISAM Caching is Simpler**

[MyISAM only caches index pages. InnoDB caches data and index pages](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194). You can thus configure the MyISAM key cache smaller that an InnoDB Buffer Pool.

**Reason # 3 : InnoDB carries too much baggage for protecting data**

InnoDB features crash recovery on startup even if nothing is wrong (precautionary)

[InnoDB always performs MVCC against rows of data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). That creates extra housecleaning for a house that never get messy from INSERTs, UPDATEs, or DELETEs.

InnoDB performs double index lookups all the time, particularly when using non-UNIQUE indexes. The reason this happens is due to [InnoDB's internal rowid index which is closely linked to the clustered index](https://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554).

You could bypass having InnoDB startup by having the following in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
```

MySQL will thus restart much quicker. You could also delete /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1, /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0, and /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1.

**CAVEAT**

If the data is small enough, mount /var/lib/mysql on a RAM disk. Then, all bets are off for comparing MyISAM to InnoDB.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/

InnoDB will outperform myiasm if you set to run the db in memory.. that is if you can fit it into memory.